# Why does Harry tell Dumbledore's Army that the unknown Horcrux is something of Ravenclaw's when he can't rule out Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

In chapter 29 of *Deathly Hallows*, Harry tells his allies that he's looking for something. Unknown to his allies, it's the last Horcrux. He tells them the following:

> It’s here at Hogwarts, but we don’t know where. It might have belonged to Ravenclaw.

Why does Harry only specify Ravenclaw here? To my knowledge, he and Dumbledore have suspected that the unknown object will be of either Ravenclaw or Gryffindor origin. Why did he not mention Gryffindor?

Comment: Going straight from memory, didn't Harry have a number of mental flashes from Voldemort about the horcruxes before then? I thought that pretty much confirmed for him that it would be something of Ravenclaw's and not Gryffindor...

Comment: @Dúthomhas No. He very specifically didn't have one for the diadem. If he did, he would've known that it was in the Room of Requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the only known relic of Gryffindor was the Sword of Gryffindor, and Voldemort couldn't have turned it into a Horcrux because it has been safe in Dumbledore possesion all this time. Thus, the safest bet is a relic from Ravenclaw.

> Four objects from the four founders would, I am sure, have exerted a powerful pull over Voldemort’s imagination. I cannot answer for whether he ever managed to find anything of Ravenclaw’s. I am confident, however, that the only known relic of Gryffindor remains safe.’
>
> Dumbledore pointed his blackened fingers to the wall behind him, where a ruby-encrusted sword reposed within a glass case.
> <sub>Rowling, J.K.. Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince . Pottermore Publishing. Edición de Kindle.</sub>

So... Dumbledore just guessed. And his guesses have been pretty good so far.

> ‘I guessed. But my guesses have, usually, been good,’ said Dumbledore
> happily,
>
> <sub>Rowling, J.K.. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (p. 580).
> Pottermore Publishing. Edición de Kindle.</sub>

Comment: And yet Harry was chanting "_something of Gryffindor’s or Ravenclaw’s_" to himself as a mantra in HBP? Something doesn't seem to quite add up.

Comment: @J.Mini You're right. It seems like Harry hadn't discarded a possible Gryffindor relic yet in HBP, but he somehow discarded it in HDH? Harry didn't attempt to search for a Gryffindor relic in Gringotts Malfoy's vault either

Comment: Didn't Harry get the Sword of Gryffindor by the time he got to Hogwarts in HDH?

Answer (score 8):

Dumbledore had essentially ruled out the possibility of a Gryffindor object. From Chapter Twenty-Three of *Half-Blood Prince*:

> “Yes,” said Dumbledore, smiling, “I would be prepared to bet — perhaps not my other hand — but a couple of fingers, that they became Horcruxes three and four. The remaining two, assuming again that he created a total of six, are more of a problem, but I will hazard a guess that, having secured objects from Hufflepuff and Slytherin, he set out to track down objects owned by Gryffindor or Ravenclaw. Four objects from the four founders would, I am sure, have exerted a powerful pull over Voldemort’s imagination. I cannot answer for whether he ever managed to find anything of Ravenclaw’s. **I am confident, however, that the only known relic of Gryffindor remains safe.”**

Comment: True, but it's Harry that matters. Harry was chanting "_something of Gryffindor’s or Ravenclaw’s_" to himself as a mantra in HBP.

Answer (score 1):

**Because of Linguistics**

As has been mentioned Harry knew via Dumbledore that the only known relic of Gryffindor  was the sword. (And the hat, if we take the Sorting Hat's song seriously that Gryffidor "Snatched [the hat] off his head" for the founders to put their brains in.  But that's another conversation.)  Harry chants "Something of Gryffindor or Ravenclaw's" because there was a chance it could have been either, with Voldemort finding something of Gryffindor's nobody knew about.  However by the time he gets back into the castle in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* time is running out.  Harry knows (via his interaction with Xenophilius Lovegood and others) that there IS a relic of Ravenclaw's (the diadem) that exists.  He still doesn't know anything about Gryffindor having another relic.

When Harry says "it might be something of Ravenclaw's" he is using linguistic device to express his thoughts.  The "might" is what's called an equivocation, and allows the speaker to express a lack of confidence in a statement.  In this case the statement is "Something of Ravenclaw's." That "might" gives Harry the ability to say "Your mention of Gryffindor's lucky matchbox IS what I was looking for! I only said it *might* be something of Ravenclaw's" while still allowing him to express his main wish, which is for somebody to tell him about a thing of Ravenclaw's.  It's a subconscious thing everyone does.  It also allows Harry to maintain face (again, subconsciously) if in fact Voldemort's last horcrux HAD been something besides a relic of Ravenclaw's.  After all, he said "might" not "100% must be!"

TL/DR: Harry says what he says because people are wired to hedge their speech when they're not absolutely sure/in a stressful situation.  it allowed him to get his main concept across "I want to find something of Ravenclaw's because I am veru sure it is the horcrux" while giving him an "out" in case he later discovered the horcrux wasn't something of ravenclaw's.